# Prove or disprove existence of a sequence converging weakly to $0$ in an infinite dim Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

This is a problem on an old analysis qual, the prompt is:

"Prove or give a counter example: if $H$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space and $0$ is the zero vector in $H$, then there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $H$ so that $||x_n|| \ge 1$ and $\{x_n\}$ converges weakly to the zero vector $0$ in $H$."

I know that the unit ball is not necessarily weakly compact in an infinite dimensional space if it is not reflexive. But this is specifying the existence of a single sequence, which doesn't say anything about every sequence having a convergent subsequence etc.

Since it is a Hilbert space I know it is equivalent to $(x_n,y) \rightarrow 0$ for all $y \in H$ for such a space. I was tempted to assume a countable orthonormal  use Parseval's Identity to show $||x_n||^2$ could be made less than 1, but this would seem to require $(x_n,e_k)$ to converge uniformly (ie independently of $k$ where the $e_k$'s are the orthonormal set).

Anyway, I am stuck. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: The statement is true. You may assume $H$ is separable. Take an orthornormal basis of $H$ and show, by Parseval e.g., that is weakly convergent to $0$. (Or just take an infinite orthonormal sequence in $H$ and use Bessel.)

Comment: Why may I assume it is separable?

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit inelegant to do so. Better to take the second, parenthetical, approach I suggested in my first comment.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I think I see

Comment: @Fractal20 then you can answer your own question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, based on David Mitra's comment we can construct an orthonormal sequence. For ease of showing the required result let's call this $\{x_n\}$. Then Bessel's inequality gives for all $y \in H$ that:

$\sum_{n=1} ^\infty |(x_n,y)|^2 \le ||y||^2$. Assume $||y||^2$ is not infinite, which seems reasonable then this is a convergent sequence which implies the terms much approach zero, hence $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (x_n,y) = 0$, thus by definition we have a sequence that converges to the 0 vector (and since it is orthonormal $||x_n|| = 1$ so it satisfies $||x_n|| \ge 1$.

I wonder why the question specified the norm being greater than or equal to 1. Just to throw to make it more confusing?

Comment: Presumably the requirement $\|x_n\| \ge 1$ is to keep you from just picking a sequence that converges to 0 in norm.

Comment: That makes sense. I suppose I meant that I was wondering why it could be greater than one, ie the proof relied on it being an orthonormal sequence which then would all have norm of 1.

Comment: Well, you could use $\{2x_n\}$.

Comment: Can you explain why we can assume ||y||^2 < infinity?

Comment: @Bob follows by definition, since $y\in H$.